# Why is my USB serial device communication garbled when using minicom and how do I fix it?

Tags: usb, serial, minicom

I have a Aoetec Z-Stick Zwave device I am playing around with. I am trying to communicate with it using minicom and I have never tried something like this before. I asked about baud rate in a discord and was told the proper baud rate was `115k IIRC`. I connect to the device using `sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyACM0` but when I turn off a light (so that I see something in the serial log) it looks like this...

[image]

This looks garbled to me but the config looks like to baud rate is 115k...

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure this _isn't_ what you're supposed to see? Not all serial communications are text-based!

Comment: @DanielB Sure can you give me an example of a config to try.

Comment: @user1686 I don't think it is right but the docs are here in case I am wrong (https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/user-guides/INS12350-Serial-API-Host-Appl.-Prg.-Guide.pdf)

Comment: As @user1686 pointed out, the API you're trying to use is not text-based but rather is a binary protocol.  Whether you can utilitize **minicom** (or any text-based terminal emulation program) will depend on circumstances and ingenuity (e.g. use a hex editor to build canned messages and then send the message file).